Change Existing JSON value "JSON_MODIFY" must be a string literal
First insert is not a problem. But update JSON value getting error. It is getting error because I am using dynamic value. However I cannot figure out how I can.
DECLARE @Index INT = (
SELECT rn - 1 
FROM (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS rn, value
    FROM OPENJSON(@CurrentJson, '$.RatedRecipes')
) AS numbered
WHERE JSON_VALUE(value, '$.Id') = @ArticleId);

IF @Index IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
   SET @CurrentJson = JSON_MODIFY(@CurrentJson, '$.RatedRecipes[' + CAST(@Index AS NVARCHAR(5)) + '].Rate', @Rate);
END
ELSE
BEGIN
   DECLARE @RateRecipe NVARCHAR(MAX);
    SET @RateRecipe = CONCAT('{"Id": "', @ArticleId, '", "Rate": ', @Rate, '}');
    
    SET @CurrentJson = JSON_MODIFY(@CurrentJson, 'append $.RatedRecipes', JSON_QUERY(@RateRecipe));
END

If I use like below not a problem. But I cannot
  SET @CurrentJson = JSON_MODIFY(@CurrentJson, '$.RatedRecipes[0].Rate', @Rate);

That is the CurrentJson
{"FollowedAuthors": [], "Recipes": [{"Id": "B88EEE77-B779-491C-97C3-CDE8C1E7DF9F", "Title": "Tart", "Url": "/recipe-tart", "Type": "Liked"}], "RatedRecipes": [{"Id": "499D486C-0CF5-4708-A818-2F86E23A9C65", "Rate": 5},{"Id": "B8522F7C-08C9-4DB9-86A3-5494461451DF", "Rate": 2}]}

@@VERSION returns

Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP2) (KB4052908) - 13.0.5026.0 (X64) Mar 18
2018 09:11:49 Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation Enterprise Edition
(64-bit) on Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard 6.3  (Build 9600: )
(Hypervisor)


What is the actual value of @CurrentJson and what is your SQL Server version?

I edited @CurrentJson and version is 17

More importantly though, why are you using loops in the first place? What are you trying to produce? It's probably FAR easier to write a proper query that extracts that data and returns the results as JSON than looping over values. You already retrieved the Recipe records with OPENSJON, why try to use .RatedRecipes[0].Rate instead of just using Rate ?

if you're on sql server 2017, you can provide a variable or expression to JSON_modify, the above code works fine for me on SQL Server 2017 - 2022

You are probably executing the statement on SQL Server 2016. In this situation you need a different approach.

SQL Server Management Studio    19.1.56.0
SQL Server Management Objects (SMO)  16.200.48044.0
Microsoft T-SQL Parser             17.0.8.0
Microsoft Analysis Services Client Tools                 16.0.20010.0
Microsoft Data Access Components (MDAC)  10.0.19041.3636
Microsoft MSXML       3.0 6.0
Microsoft .NET Framework     4.0.30319.42000
Operating System       10.0.19045

@mach, what does SELECT @@VERSION return?

SSMS isn't SQL Server, it's just a client application for DBAs. What's the actual SQL Server version?

Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP2) (KB4052908) - 13.0.5026.0 (X64)   Mar 18 2018 09:11:49   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Enterprise Edition (64-bit) on Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard 6.3  (Build 9600: ) (Hypervisor)

SQL Server 2016 is out of support. The query works in SQL Server 2019, the oldest still in mainstream support. You still haven't explained what you're trying to do though. You can get the rate without loops by using select id,rate from openjson(@CurrentJson) with (  RatedRecipes nvarchar(max) '$.RatedRecipes' as json ) outer apply openjson(RatedRecipes) with ( id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER 'strict $.Id',     Rate NVARCHAR(50) '$.Rate') 

Thank you for your all helps. I did not know the 2016 out of support. I did it like you said SET @CurrentJson = JSON_MODIFY(@CurrentJson, '$.RatedRecipes', JSON_QUERY(@UpdatedRatedRecipes)); It is worked :)

The JSON_MODIFY docs for SQL Server 2016 say that : In SQL Server 2017 (14.x) and in Azure SQL Database, you can provide a variable as the value of path. This implies you can't use a variable in 2016 without clearly saying this.

Your current statement works on SQL Server 2017+. SQL Server 2016 doesn't support a variable or expression as the value of path and this is the explanation for the error in the statement. One solution in this situation is a different approach (working on SQL Server 2016+). The idea is to parse the $.RatedRecipes part of the JSON content and transform it into a table with OPENJSON(), update/insert the new values using a SET-based approach, export the table as JSON and finally modify the original JSON with JSON_MODIFY():
SET @CurrentJson = JSON_MODIFY(
   @CurrentJson, 
   '$.RatedRecipes', 
   (
   SELECT COALESCE(v.Id, j.Id) AS Id, COALESCE(v.Rate, j.Rate) AS Rate
   FROM OPENJSON(@CurrentJson, '$.RatedRecipes') WITH (
      Id uniqueidentifier '$.Id',
      Rate INT '$.Rate'
   ) j
   FULL OUTER JOIN (VALUES (@ArticleId, @Rate)) v (Id, Rate) ON j.Id = v.Id
   FOR JSON AUTO  
   )
);  

